# Strange Java Coding Style - Why?

Tags: java, coding-style

I've just came across some code which is slightly strange, I was wondering if anyone could shed light on why it might be written like this.

I *think* it's got something to do with concurrency - so that the variables can't get changed if another thread accesses it (because variable updates aren't atomic). *Or* it's speed (because local variables are faster than class level variables?) *OR* I'm wrong on everything I've written here :)

Oh, I'm not talking about the Hungarian notation, I'm talking about the local assignments inside the methods.

```
public Class Space
{
  private double m_dWidth = 0;

  // Constructors & other methods omitted for readability
  //...

  public double getWidth()
  {
     double dWidth = m_dWidth;
     return dWidth;
  }
}
```

Comment: It has something to do with the fact that whoever wrote this code, shouldn't be writing code at all, cause it serves absolutely no use.

Comment: I see a well asked question. I don't understand the downvotes (specially when the downvoter doesn't leave a comment).

Comment: That serves absolutely no purpose and any good compiler will optimize it away

Comment: This probably won't help your question but where did you find this code? Was it in a textbook or from a new programmer? Also, `Class` shouldn't be capitalised.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the person writing the code has misunderstood how return works. It is a common misunderstanding among my java students (university first year) that return only works on locally defined variables.
Edit: putting this as an answer.

Comment: I would suspect that `getWidth` was more complicated and has since been refactored and this is a hangover from that.  I can't think of a good reason with this code sample.

Comment: If this style was used with a list in a multithreaded environment, would that be a valid use (because the list could get modified between the start of the return statement & another thread modifying it)?

Comment: @user114381 No, that would work even less as a List is a reference type so you'd still be referencing the same list. Look into the  synchronised keyword and locking to prevent multithreading issidux

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the person writing the code has misunderstood how `return` works. It is a common misunderstanding among my java students (university first year) that `return` only works on locally defined variables instead of arbitrary expressions.

As @Steve suggests, it could also be a hangover from an older, more complicated version of the code. Which one is more likely depends on where you found the code.

Answer (score 2):

I can only think of two situations where copying an instance variable to a local variable can make sense:

- if `m_dWidth` is volatile or even final and you use it more than once in a method, taking a local copy may improve performance (with the risk of missing updates, which may be acceptable) - [example in `ArrayBlockingQueue#extract`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.java#ArrayBlockingQueue.extract%28%29):

  ```
  final Object[] items = this.items;
  ```
- in some complex concurrent constructs, [such as `String#hashcode`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java#String.hashCode%28%29), where taking a local copy of a shared, non volatile, variable is necessary to ensure correctness in a  multithreaded context:

  ```
  int h = hash;
  ```

In the specific example you give, it makes no difference (apart from unnecessarily cluttering the code).

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with any of what you've wrote. Think about this piece of code:

```
class MyClass {
     private int myInt;

     //...

     public int getData() {
         return myInt;
     }

     public int strangeGetData() {
         int temp = myInt;
         return temp;
     }

     public int strangeGetData2() {
         int temp = myInt;
         int temp2 = temp;
         int temp3 = temp2;
         return temp3;
     }
}
```

When you use any of the *getters*, you'll get the same result. Note that `myInt` is a *member variable*, it can be accessed anywhere inside the class.

I advise you to go through a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) to better understand this.

Comment: Thank you, I also have no idea why the downvotes. Perhaps it's because they believe they're better than me? Strange that for a Q&A site, I get downvoted whilst asking a perfect question. Hmmm. Aaaanyway... You're right, it's part of more complex code BUT, assume this is to be used in a multithreaded environment. Could it be so that *if* another thread modified m_dWidth at exactly the same time as the return, that be assigning it to a local variable, the local (old) copy would still be returned?

Comment: @user114381 No. When you have a *multithreaded* application you deal with it in another way. Refer to [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) to better understand this.

Answer (score 0):

It should be written written without local variable. Local variable in getter is useless.

```
  public double getWidth()
  {
     return m_dWidth;
  }
```